# Issues with embeding WPF into Win32 Application

Tags: c#, c++, .net, wpf, winapi

I have a large wxWidgets (Win32) LOB application. In future I want to get rid of wxWidgets and want to go for WPF (Prism). I want to develop any new component in WPF only and expecting to embed into wxWidgets Application, so that I can reuse the same whenever I will go for full fledge WPF application.

I came across 3 approaches to host WPF component into Win32 application.

**Muliprocess architecture**

Create WPF component as exe, and use the SetParent() and MoveWindow() calls to embed it into existing Win32 application. I created POC, and is working as expected.

**Wrap WPF component with COM interface**

Both .NET and C++ supports COM. This is achievable but I did not created any POC.

**[Use the Guidelines given by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742522.aspx#hosting_a_wpf_page)**

compile C++ application as a C++/CLI application. Once it's a C++/CLI application, you can mix managed and native code easily.

If anybody already came across with situation like this, Please advise me **what are consequences** I have to face with these above approaches.

I have heard issues with focus, keyboard events and mouse events.

Comment: @Donnelle I know you are aware of this topic, your thought would be much appreciated.

Comment: You want us to list all the flaws? There are many. This does not make a good question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understand that it is a subjective topic. But it's a important thing to know how one can migrate a legacy LOB application to new things considering the fact that whole LOB application can not be re-written in new things in one shot.

Comment: Your proposed approach is worse. It won't work. `SetParent` cross process just won't cut it.